# Proving that a limit exists iff the left and right limits exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> **Proposition 3.1.16.** Let $S \subset \mathbb{R} $ be a set such that c is a cluster point of both S $\cap (-\infty, c)$ and $S \cap (c,\infty)$ let $f : S -> \mathbb R $ be a function. Then   $\lim _{x-> c}f(x) = L $ if and only if $\lim _{x-> c^-}f(x) = \lim_{x->c^+} f(x)= L$.  That is a limit exists if both one-sided limits exist and are equal, and vice-verse. The proof is a straightforward application of the definition of limit and is left as exercise. The key point is that $(S\cap(-\infty,c)) \cup (S\cap(c,\infty)) = S$\ ${c}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have a few questions... $c$ is a cluster point of both $S\cap (c,\infty)$ and what? Does $R$ denote the real numbers here? You should typeset that by `\mathbb{R}`. Finally, please use a descriptive problem, so that people are able to better find this in the future.

Comment: oh thank I fixed

Comment: Should that be $S\cap (c,\infty)$ and $S\cap (-\infty, c)$ perhaps?

Comment: yeah Sorry about that

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Do you know how to prove either direction of the implication?